# WinAppDriver : work on an uwp under development

Tags: winappdriver

With the test tool [WinAppDriver](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver), for launching the app you use the code bellow:

```
DesiredCapabilities appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", "appID");
```

but for an uwp under devlopement, how het the app id? how use the tool on an universal windows app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your app is installed, you can find the packageFullName using the following Powershell command:

Get-AppxPackage -Name

Where PackageName will be the PackageName that you specify in the AppXManifest (in the packaging tab).

Look for the PackageFamilyName, and that will be the prefix of AppId that you need to specify before the !App.

For example from the WinAppDriver input sample app:

> **Get-AppxPackage -Name WinAppDriver.Input**

```
Name              : WinAppDriver.Input
Publisher         : CN=WinAppDriver, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Architecture      : X64
ResourceId        :
Version           : 1.0.2.0
PackageFullName   : WinAppDriver.Input_1.0.2.0_x64__xh1ske9axcpv8
InstallLocation   : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\WinAppDriver.Input_1.0.2.0_x64__xh1ske9axcpv8
IsFramework       : False
PackageFamilyName : WinAppDriver.Input_xh1ske9axcpv8
PublisherId       : xh1ske9axcpv8
IsResourcePackage : False
IsBundle          : False
IsDevelopmentMode : False
Dependencies      : {Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1_1.1.25305.1_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe,
                Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.25547.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe}
IsPartiallyStaged : False
SignatureKind     : Developer
Status            : Ok
```

The AppID would be: **WinAppDriver.Input_xh1ske9axcpv8!App**